# 301 redirect - redirecting just one page with https and a subdomain

Tags: apache, .htaccess, redirect

I would like to redirect just one page to another page on the same site

Does this pattern look correct?

> Redirect 301 https://subdomain.domain.com/old-page-name
>   https://subdomain.domain.com/new-page-name

The reason I ask is that I have found various examples of redirecting just a  single page but they look like this:

> Redirect 301 /old-page-name http://www.your-domain.com/new-page-name

If I do it like this and the domain has multiple subdomains is that going to cause an issue and redirect all subdomain sites with that matching url? or is there one .htaccess file per subdomain for example

So to add to the question, if I wanted a second page to redirect the syntax would look like this?:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^subdomain\.domain\.co\.uk$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^/oldpage01 https://%{HTTP_HOST}/newpage01 [NC,R=301,L]
RewriteRule ^/oldpage02 https://%{HTTP_HOST}/newpage02 [NC,R=301,L]
```

I could just list a whole bunch like that?

Answer (score 0):

You should be using mod_rewrite rule for this to target only one subdomain. Place this in root .htaccess:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^subdomain\.domain\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^old-page-name https://%{HTTP_HOST}/new-page-name [NC,R=301,L]
```

**EDIT:** Based on your edited question you can use this code:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^subdomain\.domain\.co\.uk$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^oldpage01 https://%{HTTP_HOST}/newpage01 [NC,R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^subdomain\.domain\.co\.uk$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^oldpage02 https://%{HTTP_HOST}/newpage02 [NC,R=301,L]
```

Comment: Thanks i will try this, so to set up 2 redirects would I just list all the rewrite rules 1 after the other? So 1 ReWriteCond followed by 2 ReWriteRule or do i have to write out all of the example for each url i want to change?

Comment: It depends upon your requirement for the 2nd redirect rule. If you let me know what you need in 2nd rule then I can suggest better.

Comment: sorry i can't do formatting in the comments i will add it to the question

Comment: it is always better to edit the question so you did the right thing. Look at edited answer now.